# Count occurrence truth value in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, comparison

Close and open are two fields in pandas Dataframe. I need to find the number of occurrence where Close is greater that zero.

```
wipro['Close'] > wipro['Open']
```

It give below result. How can I count the number of occurrence of True.

```
Date
2015-01-01    False
2015-01-02     True
2015-01-05     True
2015-01-06    False
2015-01-07    False
2015-01-08    False
2015-01-09     True
2015-01-12     True
2015-01-13     True
```

I tried storing the value in list and count occurrence of  Truth but did not work out:

```
list = [wipro['Close'] > wipro['Open']]

list.count(True)
```

```
error:The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(),
a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

This has to be pretty simple task but I am unable to find the result.

Comment: `(wipro['Close'] > wipro['Open']).value_counts()`? or just `sum` if you only care about `True`.  Also, don't name variables `list`, it overrides a builtin constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
(wipro['Close'] > wipro['Open']).sum()
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked out. Tried whole lot of things and missed out on this one.